# How do I consumer a WSE WebService in VS2015?

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio-2015, wse

I am trying to connect to the Ohio Finder Service to obtain local sales tax information.  The documentation for the service, and the endpoint address are available via:

https://thefinder.tax.ohio.gov/streamlinesalestaxweb/webservice/about.aspx

The service is free to use, but does require a user registration.

In order to add the service reference, I followed these steps:

1. Right click on references, and select ‘Add Service Reference’
2. Click on ‘Advanced’ to open the Service Reference Settings
3. Click on ‘Add Web Reference’ under the Compatibility section.
4. Supplied the service endpoint ‘https://thefinder.tax.ohio.gov/OHFinderService/OHFinderService.asmx’ and clicked to discover the service.  The OHFinderService was found at the URL, so I added the reference.

The reference added successfully but I am missing the WSE object that is used to authenticate to the service.

I tried adding the following configuration under the  configuration section:

```
<webServices>
      <soapExtensionImporterTypes>
        <add type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Description.WseExtensionImporter, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </soapExtensionImporterTypes>
      <soapServerProtocolFactory type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.WseProtocolFactory, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
 </webServices>
```

After adding the configuration section I clicked  on 'Update Web Reference', but I did not get the WSE object.

Any ideas on how I can connect to a legacy WSE service using VS2015?

**UPDATE:**
I am having no luck getting the WSE object to show up in visual studio.  The end goal here is to connect to the service and obtain rate information.  With that in mind, I am heading down a parallel path of trying to construct the SOAP request myself.  Thus far I am getting an internal server error when I place the request.  The specification for the service may be found in the site linked above.

Here is the XML that I am sending with my request.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
                   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:si="http://soapinterop.org/xsd"
                   xmlns:ns5925="https://thefinder.tax.ohio.gov/OHFinderService/OHFinderService.asmx"
                   xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security>
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>MYUSERNAME</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="wsse: PasswordText">MYPASSWORD</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <GetOHSalesTaxByZipCode xmlns="https://thefinder.tax.ohio.gov/OHFinderService/OHFinderService.asmx">
            <PostalCode>43230</PostalCode><SalesAmount>10.00</SalesAmount><SalesDate>4%2f5%2f2018</SalesDate><ReturnMultiple>false</ReturnMultiple>
        </GetOHSalesTaxByZipCode>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is the code I am using to build the XML

```
public class WebServiceHelper
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Params = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public XDocument ResultXML;
    public string ResultString;

    public WebServiceHelper()
    {

    }

    public WebServiceHelper(string url, string methodName)
    {
        Url = url;
        MethodName = methodName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes service
    /// </summary>
    public void Invoke()
    {
        Invoke(true);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invokes service
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="encode">Added parameters will encode? (default: true)</param>
    public void Invoke(bool encode)
    {
        string soapStr =
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO-8859-1""?>
                <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" 
                                   xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""  
                                   xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""
                                   xmlns:si=""http://soapinterop.org/xsd""
                                   xmlns:ns5925=""https://thefinder.tax.ohio.gov/OHFinderService/OHFinderService.asmx""
                                   xmlns:wsse=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext"">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header>
                <wsse:Security>
                    <wsse:UsernameToken>
                        <wsse:Username>USERNAMEHERE</wsse:Username>
                        <wsse:Password Type=""wsse: PasswordText"">PASSWORDHERE</wsse:Password>
                    </wsse:UsernameToken>
                </wsse:Security>
           </SOAP-ENV:Header> 
           <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <{0} xmlns=""https://thefinder.tax.ohio.gov/OHFinderService/OHFinderService.asmx"">
              {1}
            </{0}>
          </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"https://thefinder.tax.ohio.gov/OHFinderService/" + MethodName + "\"");
        req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        req.Accept = "text/xml";
        req.Method = "POST";

        using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            string postValues = "";
            foreach (var param in Params)
            {
                if (encode)
                    postValues += string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param.Key), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(param.Value));
                else
                    postValues += string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", param.Key, param.Value);
            }

            soapStr = string.Format(soapStr, MethodName, postValues);
            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
            {
                stmw.Write(soapStr);
            }
        }

        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            ResultXML = XDocument.Parse(result);
            ResultString = result;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am calling this code:

```
            WebServiceHelper ws = new WebServiceHelper("https://thefinder.tax.ohio.gov/OHFinderService/OHFinderService.asmx", "GetOHSalesTaxByZipCode");
        ws.Params.Add("PostalCode", "43230");
        ws.Params.Add("SalesAmount", "10.00");
        ws.Params.Add("SalesDate", DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
        ws.Params.Add("ReturnMultiple", "false");
        ws.Invoke();
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?  My guess is that I am constructing the request incorrectly...

Comment: Do you need to connect to it using a reference? You can simply consume it using `HttpRequest` or `HttpClient`. That way you will have much more control.

Comment: this question is a little vague on what your trying to do.  Are you not able to create an instance of the object?  You cannot just reference the WSE service directly.  You must create a local instance of the service and call the methods on that instance

Comment: It does not have to be using the reference.  When I try to create the request myself by building the XML i am getting an internal server error... I will add the code I am using to the question above...

Answer (score 1):

Web Service Enhancements 3 (WSE 3) is not officially supported since Visual Studio 2008.

We have to install WSE 3.0 then integrate in Visual studio manually.

please use this [link](https://digantakumar.com/2010/06/04/wse-3-in-visual-studio-2008-and-2010/) to access wse service in VS 2015 .

Comment: When I installed this, the WseSettingsVS3.dll is missing from the install folder.  I'll give it another try though...

Comment: it will work, we faced same type of problem for our legacy web service once.

Comment: Unfortunately, after following the steps and restarting visual studio the menu still does not appear.  I'll try uninstalling, and reinstalling to attempt the process once more -- but at the moment it's not looking too good.

Comment: after installing WSE try remove and "Add Service Reference" again , now new code generated will be according to WSE standard.